# Show file names with the full path in the frame title

Tags: frames

I want to set the frame title as follows:

- When the current buffer is visiting a file, show the full path name and the Emacs version.
- When the current buffer has no file, then show the buffer name and the Emacs version.

In my `init.el`, I put

```
(setq-default frame-title-format
  (concat (if (buffer-file-name) "%f" "%b") " - " (substring (emacs-version) 0 15)))
```

But here is the result:[image: screenshot with the title containing a file name without the full path]

Why doesn't my code print the file name with the full path?

Answer (score 9):

Because you're setting `frame-title-format` to `"%b - GNU Emacs 26.1 "`.

You can try the following instead

```
(setq frame-title-format
      `((buffer-file-name "%f" "%b")
        ,(format " - GNU Emacs %s" emacs-version)))
```

The following does the same but it probably does some unneeded work (that is, computing the version string) repeatedly

```
(setq frame-title-format
      (list '(buffer-file-name "%f" "%b")
            '(:eval (format " - GNU Emacs %s" emacs-version))))
```

Comment: It's work. Nice. But what is different between (format " - GNU Emacs %s" emacs-version)) and '(:eval (format " - GNU Emacs %s" emacs-version)) ?

Comment: FYI, OP: @rpluim answered the question in your comment.

Comment: @xuchunyang I'd forgotten about the `(symbol then else)` form for `mode-line-format`, nice one.

Comment: @Alexei The value of `(format " - GNU Emacs %s" emacs-version)` is a constant and is known when Emacs starts. If you use `'(:eval (format ...))`, Emacs will compute it whenever the frame title needs to be updated, which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs is evaluating your expression at the time when you setq `frame-title-format`, whereas you want it to be evaluated dynamically. Try wrapping your code in `:eval` as explained at [Mode-Line-Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html#Mode-Line-Data)

Comment: I need when create/open buffer to evaluate on fly is this is a buffer with or not file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To show the real file name in the titlebar, not just the buffer name, with the additional dired buffer case, and the last default to the buffer name:

```
(setq frame-title-format
      '(buffer-file-name (:eval (abbreviate-file-name buffer-file-name))
                         (dired-directory dired-directory
                                          "%b")))
```

As the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html) explains, in those cases the first symbol specifies a conditional (`buffer-file-name`, `dired-directory`). The two steps form and the `:eval` clause *might* slow down redisplay, though.